# Core Data won't release UIImage data from memory (ImageIO_PNG_Data)

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uiimageview, uiimage

My app has view that renders some details about an Entity and a UIScrollView with some UIImageViews of related thumbnail images (all held in core data). When the user presses a thumbnail I fetch the full size image (from core data) and render it in a UIImageView. The images were captured to Core Data from the device camera or photo album. Saving/retrieving of the UIImage works just fine. The data is normalized as recommended by Apple to minimize loading large objects until needed.

Sorry for the long post but wanted to be thorough...

**The Core Data setup:**

The top level Entity is a `WalkthruItem` which has a to-many relationship to `WalkthruItemImage` that holds the thumbnail (Transformable) and comments.  The actual full-size images are then stored in a to-one related object `WalkthruItemImageImage` which has a single Transformable property called 'image'. This is done to keep from loading the full size image when showing all of the thumbnails. (Can't post images of the Editor, sorry) The full size image only gets loaded when the thumbnail is pressed as you'll see in the code below.

**The issue:**

When loading images (both thumbnails and full size) the ImageIO_PNG_Data never gets released. Ever. Even after a memory warning. Of course the eventual crash works perfectly :)

I eventually load these images into a UIImageView and then (I think) properly release them.

The unreleased data presents as **ImageIO_PNG_Data** in instruments. Typically they are 14.77 MB as they were captured by the camera (5s) and I assume that's their fully decompressed size. The number of ImageIO_PNG_Data objects exactly matches the number of **unique** images I've loaded. Loading the same image later does not increase the memory footprint so it looks like it's Core Data trying to do some caching for me that I really don't need.

**Image loading code:**

Here is the code that pulls the full size image in response to the thumbnail being pressed and then puts it into a UIImageView. The case is a bit contrived since I simplified it for this question. Normally there is a segue and some fancy UIImageView container but this case shows the exact memory issue in a much easier to document fashion. Some failed attempts at a fix are commented out in the code and discussed in the 'What I tried' section below:

```
if(viewHit.tag>-1){
        currentImageIndexForPreview = viewHit.tag;

        // this object holds the thumbnail
        DCWalkthruItemImage * itemImage = self.walkthruItem.images[currentImageIndexForPreview];

        // itemImage.image (1:1 relationship) gets the DCWalkthruItemImageImage object
        // itemImage.image.image gets the actual image data
        UIImage *image = itemImage.image.image;

        // this below attempt doubles the temporarily allocated memory but then frees half of it when the UIImageViews are dealloced
        // essentially the same problem but seems to prove that it's not the UIImageView holding the reference
        //UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(itemImage.image.image)];

        // simplified case of just throwing an imageView up on the controller's view
        UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(testImageViews.count * 10, testImageViews.count * 10, 100, 100);
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
        [testImageViews addObject:imageView];

        //  attempts to free references
        itemImage.image.image = nil;
        [self.managedObjectContext refreshObject:itemImage.image mergeChanges:false];
    }
```

**Release code:**

I just call this code from a button press to release the UIImageViews

```
-(void) cleanup{
LogInfo(@"%d images", testImages.count)
for (UIImageView* imageView in testImageViews){
    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
    imageView.image = nil;
}
[testImageViews removeAllObjects];;
}
```

**What I've tried**

- Read what I could find on SO but the Core Data related items don't seem to apply.

  - Most are about how to store a UIImage
  - The UIImageView related questions all seem to deal with images that were loaded from resources or via HTTP. This issues seems to be Core Data holding on to the memory as opposed to the UIImageView which I think I proved above
- Switched to using an NSValueTransformer to force the data to/from a UIImage to NSData when storing in Core Data. This made no difference since it seems Core Data was smart enuff and just did that for me even without this transformer. The code of that transformer is below and is currently being used since all the advice I read says to use one and I guessed that would be the first recommendation. But like I said, just setting the property to Transformable seems to allow Core Data to do it for me.
- Tried various combinations of the following:

  - setting the UIImageView.image property to nil before removing it from its parent view
  - setting the image property of my ManagedObject to nil after I get the data
  - using `UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(itemImage.image.image)];` to create the image with a copy of the Core Data object. This results in double the memory being allocated until the UIImageViews are dealloced and the it frees half of the memory just as you would expect. This seems to prove that it's not the UIImageViews holding on to that extra memory. (This is commented in the code)
  - try the `[managedObjectContext refreshObject:itemImage.image mergeChanges:false]` to convince Core Data that I really don't care about that data and it can let it go
  - tried using a NSValueTransformer used on the image property with the same result as when I have no code on the Transformable property. Core Data seems happy to do this transformation for me. The current state of the code is using my transformer

**Here is the transformer code**:

This is set up in the Transformer Name property of the property sheet in the Core Data editor.

```
@interface DCUIImageToNSDataTransformer : NSValueTransformer
@end

#import "DCUIImageToNSDataTransformer.h"


@implementation DCUIImageToNSDataTransformer {

}

+ (Class)transformedValueClass {
    return [NSData class];
}

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation {
    return YES;
}

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {
    return UIImagePNGRepresentation(value);
}

- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value {
    return [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:value];
}

@end
```

Comment: How are you loading up your images initially?  It looks like your itemImages are already loaded into memory somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, the self.walkthruItem is loaded in viewDidLoad. Its .images NSSet is just accessed via the .images property. At this point in the code that NSSet has already been used to populate the thumbnails in the UIScrollView. The WalkthruItemImage objects held in that NSSet only hold the thumbnail and an NSString comment.

The call to itemImage.image.image is what pulls the actual full size image from Core Data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reset the Core Data object otherwise it will retain the binary data.  This is one of many reasons why it is not a good idea to store binary data in Core Data.  You are better off storing the images on disk and keep just the file pointer in Core Data itself.

To reset the `NSManagedObject` you need to call:

```
NSManagedObject *myImageObject = ...;
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = ...;
[moc refreshObject:myImageObject mergeChanges:NO];
```

That will turn the object into a fault and all of its values will be dropped from memory.

You can also force a context wide refresh by calling `-reset` on the `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Comment: Regarding Core Data vs. file system for UIImages. Up to this point Core data has been very simple to use and the cascading delete along with nearly zero code has been handy. With the image size and the way I'm storing them they probably end up on disk anyway. I do see your point but I thought I'd go this route until it failed me in some way.

Comment: I do make that call as the last line of the Image Loading code. I will toy around that part of it some more and maybe try to refresh the parent object or something. I had hoped this would be the key to Core Data letting go of that memory.

Comment: Yup, that was it, thanks. Instead of passing the actual object I want to free I need to pass its parent. Not sure why... Perhaps I should buy your book :)

So instead of:
`[self.managedObjectContext refreshObject:itemImage.image mergeChanges:false];`

I had to:
`[self.managedObjectContext refreshObject:itemImage mergeChanges:false];`

Comment: In Objective-C it is `NO` not `false` :)

Answer (score 0):

Growing memory issue most of the time come cause of 2 ways:

1.Check you image resolution which you are using in you code, use required image resolution only.

Suppose you are using 40x40 image size for 1X, 80x80 in 2x so on.. Then use only required resolution not more then that.

Check you are using updated Lazy loading library.
Use Memory Allocation tool and check VM allocation, if you got any IMAGEIO regarding issue then defiantly you have contained high resolution image in you NSMainBundle.

Resize high resolution image in required resolution and use imageWithContentsOfFile instead of imageName.